# Generating multiple Tensorboard directories

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard

I'm trying to run the same training  and Test in a loop, while changing some parameters. Each time the training is done, Tensorflow sould generate a new Tensorboard directory.

And that's exactly the problem I have:

```
........................
def generatingTBFolder(index):
    global TB_Folder
    TB_Folder ='TB_Graphs_'+str(index)


with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
    for k in range(2,5):## here is the problem 
        generatingTBFolder(k)
        train(k,numberOFclasses)
```

I don't use  a loop like :

```
with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
        generatingTBFolder(3)
        train(3,numberOFclasses)
```

the program works fine and generate a TB folder with the result. but using the loop delivers the following :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\users\engine\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in _do_call(self, fn, *args)
   1038     try:
-> 1039       return fn(*args)
   1040     except errors.OpError as e:

c:\users\engine\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in _run_fn(session, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, options, run_metadata)
   1020                                  feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list,
-> 1021                                  status, run_metadata)
   1022 

c:\users\engine\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\contextlib.py in __exit__(self, type, value, traceback)
     65             try:
---> 66                 next(self.gen)
     67             except StopIteration:

c:\users\engine\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\errors_impl.py in raise_exception_on_not_ok_status()
    465           compat.as_text(pywrap_tensorflow.TF_Message(status)),
--> 466           pywrap_tensorflow.TF_GetCode(status))
    467   finally:

InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'input/Features_values' with dtype float
     [[Node: input/Features_values = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-54a526dfc682> in <module>()
    238     for k in range(2,5):
    239         generatingTBFolder(k)
--> 240         train(k,numberOFclasses)

<ipython-input-2-54a526dfc682> in train(numberOfFeatures, numberOFclasses)
    208     for i in range(max_steps):
    209         if i%5 ==0: # Record summarie and Test-set accruracy
--> 210             summary, acc = sess.run([merged,accuracy], feed_dict=feed_dict(False))
    211             #summary, acc = sess.run([merged,accuracy], feed_dict={x:np.reshape(Test_Frame.values[:,indices[0:numberOfFeatures]],[len(Test_Frame),numberOfFeatures]),y_:np.asarray(Test_Frame.iloc[:,-1]),keep_prob:0.9})
    212             test_writer.add_summary(summary,i)

c:\users\engine\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in run(self, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
    776     try:
    777       result = self._run(None, fetches, feed_dict, options_ptr,
--> 778                          run_metadata_ptr)
    779       if run_metadata:
    780         proto_data = tf_session.TF_GetBuffer(run_metadata_ptr)

c:\users\engine\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in _run(self, handle, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
    980     if final_fetches or final_targets:
    981       results = self._do_run(handle, final_targets, final_fetches,
--> 982                              feed_dict_string, options, run_metadata)
    983     else:
    984       results = []

c:\users\engine\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in _do_run(self, handle, target_list, fetch_list, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
   1030     if handle is None:
   1031       return self._do_call(_run_fn, self._session, feed_dict, fetch_list,
-> 1032                            target_list, options, run_metadata)
   1033     else:
   1034       return self._do_call(_prun_fn, self._session, handle, feed_dict,

c:\users\engine\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in _do_call(self, fn, *args)
   1050         except KeyError:
   1051           pass
-> 1052       raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
   1053 
   1054   def _extend_graph(self):

InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'input/Features_values' with dtype float
     [[Node: input/Features_values = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]

Caused by op 'input/Features_values', defined at:
  File "c:\users\engine\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\runpy.py", line 184, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\users\engine\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "c:\users\engine\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\__main__.py", line 3, in <module>
    app.launch_new_instance()
  File "c:\users\engine\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 658, in launch_instance
    app.start()
  File "c:\users\engine\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelapp.py", line 474, in start
    ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
  File "c:\users\engine\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\zmq\eventloop\ioloop.py", line 177, in start
    super(ZMQIOLoop, self).start()
  File "c:\users\engine\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\tornado\ioloop.py", line 887, in start
    handler_func(fd_obj, events)
  File "c:\users\engine\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\tornado\stack_context.py", line 275, in null_wrapper
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\engine\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\zmq\eventloop\zmqstream.py", line 440, in _handle_events
    self._handle_recv()
  File "c:\users\engine\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\zmq\eventloop\zmqstream.py", line 472, in _handle_recv
    self._run_callback(callback, msg)
  File "c:\users\engine\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\zmq\eventloop\zmqstream.py", line 414, in _run_callback
    callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\engine\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\tornado\stack_context.py", line 275, in null_wrapper
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\engine\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 276, in dispatcher
    return self.dispatch_shell(stream, msg)
  File "c:\users\engine\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 228, in dispatch_shell
    handler(stream, idents, msg)
  File "c:\users\engine\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 390, in execute_request
    user_expressions, allow_stdin)
  File "c:\users\engine\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\ipkernel.py", line 196, in do_execute
    res = shell.run_cell(code, store_history=store_history, silent=silent)
  File "c:\users\engine\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\zmqshell.py", line 501, in run_cell
    return super(ZMQInteractiveShell, self).run_cell(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\engine\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2717, in run_cell
    interactivity=interactivity, compiler=compiler, result=result)
  File "c:\users\engine\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2821, in run_ast_nodes
    if self.run_code(code, result):
  File "c:\users\engine\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2881, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-1-54a526dfc682>", line 240, in <module>
    train(k,numberOFclasses)
  File "<ipython-input-1-54a526dfc682>", line 90, in train
    x =tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,numberOfFeatures],name='Features_values')
  File "c:\users\engine\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\array_ops.py", line 1507, in placeholder
    name=name)
  File "c:\users\engine\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_array_ops.py", line 1997, in _placeholder
    name=name)
  File "c:\users\engine\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py", line 768, in apply_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "c:\users\engine\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 2336, in create_op
    original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
  File "c:\users\engine\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 1228, in __init__
    self._traceback = _extract_stack()

InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'input/Features_values' with dtype float
     [[Node: input/Features_values = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]
```

I've already seen this error, when I start  a Tensorflow program and it crashes because of shape error or any non syntax  error, starting the same program without restarting the python kernel delivers that the same error message. 
The problem no is I really need to do that in a loop ( 500 is the actual limit) so there is no way to do it manually.

Any idea how may I solve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround to this issue, by starting the whole script using another one, that uses a loop:

```
if __name__ == "__main__" :
    with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
        print("Got ", int(sys.argv[1]))
        generatingTBFolder(int(sys.argv[1]))
        train(int(sys.argv[1]),numberOFclasses)
```

And here is the script:

```
import os
for i in range(2,456):
    command="python TensorCode.py "+str(i)
    os.system(command)
```

the result looks good in Tensorboard. 
hope this may helps someone out there ! 
[image]